# Xml long processing

Tags: php, xml

I have an php file which generates epg xml file for iptv channel. Problem is when stb access xml it can take more than 20 seconds to show xml output (stb timeout is 20sec, so xml which are not loaded are not showing epg), because php file that generate epg is actually loading data as json from remote server (after sending post request with login info). So i can not speed up the process. My question is: how do i cache it so loading can be faster. Im using cloudflare but not caching it.. Any suggestions?
Here are my epg files

tvsrbija.online/program

they are php but can be accessed with xml extension too i used htaccess to rewrite it.

Comment: You may want to change php code, so code generates an actual xml file and then you setup cron which will do that once a day or every 4 hours? That way your stb will get xml file in a second and it wont wait every time for your server to get json and parse it as xml.